# Is $\mathbb R$ with usual topology a Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb R$ with usual topology is a Hausdorff space. By the definition of Hausdorff space, for any two distinct point in $\mathbb R$ we can find  disjoint neighbourhoods... Now consider the set $A$=$\{{{1}\over{n}}\}$  where  $n\in \mathbb N$. We know that the sequence $\{{{1}\over{n}}\}$ converges to "$0$". Clearly $0$ does not belong to $A$, that is every point in $A$ and the point $0$ are distinct. Hence by definition of Hausdorff space we can find a neighbourhood of $0$ which does not intersect $A$. This shows that $0$ is not a limit point. This is contradiction to ${{1}\over {n}}\rightarrow 0$. Is my opinion is correct? please spot where i make mistake?
my thought: consider every point in $A$ and the point $0$, we can get disjoint neighbourhoods because they are disjoint. In this way of thinking I am getting lot of complications.. what can I do?

Comment: For any **two** distinct points in $\Bbb R$, you can find disjoint neighborhoods. Your problem is that you're trying to separate infinitely many points at once.

Comment: Hausdorff  space  guarantees  existence  of  two  distinct  nbd's  for  two  distinct  points ,  and  this  can  be  taken  up to  finitely  many  as  well ,  but  it  never  assures  existence  of   infinitely  many  disjoint  nbd's  for  infinitely  many  distinct  points.

Comment: @user118494 what do you mean by " but it never assures existence of infinitely many disjoint nbd's for infinitely many distinct points"?

Comment: @AvinashN  :  You  don't  get  it ?  The  answer  is  right  in  your  post !  You   already   have    given  a  counter  example   to  that  with  the  set  $A$  and  the  point  $0$ ?

Comment: @user118494 thanks

Comment: I cannot give each of the points in $\{0,\dots,\frac13,\frac12,1\}$ a neighborhood, disjoint from each other. However, I can give the points in $\{0,1\}$ disjoint neighborhoods, and I can give the points in $\{0,\frac12\}$ disjoint neighborhoods, etc. (No guarantee I'm giving $0$ the same neighborhood each time, though.)

Comment: Being Hausdorff means that, if $a$ and $b$ are in the space, there are neighborhoods $N_a$ of $a$ and $N_b$ of $b$ such that $N_a\cap N_b=\varnothing$.

Comment: now i am getting a new doubt... consider the point 0 and next real number followed by 0... i think these are distinct... so can i find disjoint neighbourhoods of these points?

Comment: Being Hausdorff means that, if a and b are in the space, there are neighborhoods Na of a and Nb of b such that Na∩Nb=∅ provided a not equal to b.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff, since for any two points $a$ and $b$, we can take the sets $N_a=(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ and $N_b=(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon\le\frac{a+b}2$. I recommend you _draw out_ this situation, on the number line.

Comment: @columbus8myhw yes correct... clearly in this set  {0,…,1/3,1/2,1} the point 0 and other points are distinct.... so..

Comment: @columbus8myhw dear sir... how to understand this with out drawing?

Comment: In your counterexample, what are $a$ and $b$? (In response to your "new doubt," there _is_ no next real number after $0$.)

Comment: (Also, can you come up with an example of a space that's _not_ Hausdorff?)

Comment: i think indiscreate topological spaces are not Hausdorff...

Comment: Yup. Also the [cofinite topology](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Finite_Complement_Topology) on $\mathbb R$ (a set is open if its empty or if its complement is finite). Same for the topology on $\mathbb R$ generated by sets of the form $(-\infty,a)$. Also [this lovely space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).

Answer (score 6):

You didn't take a *point*, you took a *sequence* of points. That's not just one point, that's infinitely many points.

Each $\frac1n$ and $0$ can be easily separated by the intervals $(-1,\frac1{4n})$ and $(\frac1{2n},2)$.

Comment: i think (1/2n,2) is not a neighbourhood of 0.

Comment: But I'm almost entirely sure that $(-1,\frac1{4n})$ is.

Comment: when putting n=1..

Comment: You get $(-1,\frac14)$ and $(\frac12,2)$. Also two disjoint intervals, one of which is around $0$ and another around $1$.

Comment: yes correct.. when n thends to infinity what happens?

Comment: The intervals get smaller. You still get that for ***each*** $\frac1n$ there is such two intervals. There is no interval that separates $0$ from ***all*** the $\frac1n$ simultaneously. But where does it say that there should be?

Comment: You should probably switch around $0$ and $\frac1n$ in your last sentence, because people usually expect things to be done respectively. (Like, you can't say "respectively" at the end.) Not necessary, but…

Comment: @columbus8myhw Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For any member of your set you can find disjoint neighbourhoods of that point and zero - do you agree with that? Problem is that you can't take one that works for all points in your set.

Comment: When working with all points it is not possible... But i got some complications. Can you clarify my confusion?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two distinct points $x$ and $y$ with $x\lt y$. How about setting $\varepsilon =\cfrac {y-x}3$? Can you see disjoint neighbourhoods emerging?

Comment: yes thats enough...  ε=(y−x)/2 it is also enough...

Answer (score 0):

given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, where $a<b$, one can find a middle point so that

$$
a< \frac{a+b}{2} <b
$$

so

- $( 2a - \frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{a+b}{2} )$ is centered at $a$
- $( \frac{a+b}{2}, 2b-\frac{a+b}{2} )$  is centered at $b$.
- the two intervals are open in **order topology** (the standard topology defined in $\mathbb{R}$) in $\mathbb{R}$.
- the two intervals are disjoint.

For $0$ and $1/n$, the two intervals are $( -\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n} )$ and $( \frac{1}{2n},\frac{3}{2n} )$.

I suppose your mental struggling is whether $\frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{n}  $ when $n \rightarrow  \infty$ so both terms "become" zero. Probably this has puzzled crazy people like Dedekind or Cantor.